# apt-get upgrade is taking forever. (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, update-manager

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Network: LAN (25Mbps confirmed using fast.com)

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The download time for above command is too much. I tried to follow [THIS](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2346051) thread. The slow speed issue is still not resolved and I am getting new errors

**PS: I have tried different Ubuntu servers but the problem persists.**

[screen shot of apt-get upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAEXH.png)

```
$ time sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  freepats gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers libavresample-ffmpeg2 libbs2b0
  libde265-0 libflite1 libfluidsynth1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgtkglext1 libllvm4.0 libmimic0
  libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libmms0 libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 libmplex2-2.1-0 libofa0 libsodium18 libsoundtouch1 libspandsp2
  libsrtp0 libtbb2 libwildmidi-config libwildmidi1 libzbar0 libzmq5 linux-image-4.10.0-28-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic linux-signed-image-4.10.0-28-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  libmm-glib0 libqmi-proxy linux-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
  linux-signed-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-signed-image-generic-hwe-16.04 modemmanager
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cpp-5 curl distro-info-data firefox firefox-locale-en fwupdate fwupdate-signed g++-5 gcc-5 gcc-5-base
  gcc-5-base:i386 gfortran-5 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome-software gnome-software-common
  grub-common grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub2-common iproute2 libasan2 libatomic1
  libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libegl1-mesa libfwup0 libgbm1 libgcc-5-dev libgfortran-5-dev
  libgfortran3 libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
  libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386 libgles2-mesa libgomp1 libitm1 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 liblsan0
  libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy libmpx0 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 libpam-systemd libpython2.7 libpython2.7-minimal
  libpython2.7-stdlib libquadmath0 libstdc++-5-dev libstdc++6 libstdc++6:i386 libsystemd0 libsystemd0:i386
  libtasn1-6 libtasn1-6:i386 libtsan0 libubsan0 libudev1 libudev1:i386 libwayland-egl1-mesa libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 libxatracker2 light-themes linux-firmware mesa-common-dev mesa-va-drivers
  mesa-vdpau-drivers python2.7 python2.7-minimal suru-icon-theme systemd systemd-sysv thunderbird
  thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-mobile-icons
  ubuntu-mono ubuntu-software udev update-notifier update-notifier-common
92 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 243 MB of archives.
After this operation, 10.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libpam-systemd amd64 229-4ubuntu21.1 [116 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libudev1 amd64 229-4ubuntu21.1 [54.9 kB]         
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 libudev1 i386 229-4ubuntu21.1 [58.0 kB]           
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 udev amd64 229-4ubuntu21.1 [992 kB]              
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 libsystemd0 i386 229-4ubuntu21.1 [222 kB]                                                                                                                               
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libsystemd0 amd64 229-4ubuntu21.1 [205 kB]       
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 systemd amd64 229-4ubuntu21.1                  
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 systemd-sysv amd64 229-4ubuntu21.1 [12.2 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libpython2.7 amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3 [1,070 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 python2.7 amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3 [224 kB]
Err:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libpython2.7-stdlib amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 systemd amd64 229-4ubuntu21.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
3% [Waiting for headers]
```

Comment: I agree with you on this point and I have removed all those errors; now apt-get update is much faster. But problem still persists with apt-get upgrade.

Comment: apt upgrade processes are pretty disk intensive. You may have [a hard disk failing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1/528077)

Comment: Looks like a networking issue. If you have an otherwise reasonably fast and stable internet connection you may want to [try a repository mirror](/q/37753/175814).